# Can anyone tell me why there is an error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having error in my code, this is not working properly can anyone tell me where is the problem?

```
<?php
   class Blog extends CI_controller {

    public function jay()
    {   
        $this->load->model('abc');
        $this->load->getdata();

        print_r($data);
        $this->load->view("page1.php");
    }
  /*public function wel()
    {
        $this->load->view('Welcome_message');
    } */

  }
?>
```

Comment: Indent your code and explain your problem, what issue you are getting in which condition /

Comment: and tell me what is this ? `$this->load->getdata();`

Comment: What is the error?  When asking a question here, you should include the *full* error message along with the code.

Comment: You do not need to use .php for views  `$this->load->view("page");`

Comment: And this guide good http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Answer (score 3):

If the method `getdata();` is inside your model you can not access it by using
$this->load function.
you can access it by `$this->abc->getdata();`

Comment: And, in the question's code the variable `$data` is not defined. This too will produce a PHP error from the line `print_r($data);`